# Preventing an SMS from going to Inbox?

Tags: android

I have read most of the questions that were about preventing the SMS from going to the Inbox. Nothing worked for me. So, I have now two applications, one is a send and the other is the receiver. The receiver needs to check the first four char of the message, if it is from the Sender app. Then, prevent it from going to the Inbox. 
They said I have to raise the priority of the the app. I did, here is my manifest

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"> 
        <intent-filter android:priority="100"> 
            <action android:name=
                "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>

</application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

And, to make it clear, here are my activity which checks the message.

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
 {

   //---get the SMS message passed in---
      final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        try {

            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);

                    H = currentMessage.getMessageBody(); 
                   // Show Alert
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, 
                                 "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);

                    toast.show();
                    if(i==0)
                        H = currentMessage.getMessageBody(); 


                } // end for loop
              } // bundle is null

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

        }

        check_message = message_checked(H) ; 

       //---display the new SMS message---
        if(check_message)
        {
       Intent intentHome = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
       intentHome.putExtra("msgContent", message);

       intentHome.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       context.startActivity(intentHome);
        }
        else 
            System.exit(0); 

   }                         

public boolean message_checked(String the_message)
{
String Code = new String("*%#&"); 
String four_char = "" ; 
for(int i = 0 ; i<4 ; i++)
{
    four_char += the_message.charAt(i) ; 

}
if(four_char.equals(Code))
{
    this.abortBroadcast();

    return true;
}
else 
    return false ; 



}
```

Did I do anything wrong ? If I did so, where is the mistake. I still receive the sms in the inbox though the app is working as I want.

Comment: try this `android:priority="9999"`

Comment: Yes, my app gets the sms before the default inbox. But still I have it in the inBox

Comment: Do you want to delete the SMS once your app read the SMS ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. If the SMS wasn't meant for the Receiver, let it be in the InBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i did it in the past, sorry my emulator is not working now so i can't check. hope it helps.

```
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){

                        // Check if the SMS matches our SOS message
                        SmsMessage[] messages = getMessagesFromIntent(intent);
                        if(messages != null){
                                for(int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++){
                                        SmsMessage message = messages[i];
                                        if(matchesMessage(context,message.getDisplayMessageBody())){
                                                Log.i(LOGNAME, "Received Test String! Abort Broadcast");
                                //put intent call or preferred code here

                                                this.abortBroadcast();
                                                break;
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }

        }

    private boolean matchesMessage(Context context, String message){

            SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(MainSetting.PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String testMessage = preferences.getString(MainSetting.PREFERENCES_TEST, MainSetting.PREFERENCES_STRING_DEFAULT); //this is a string stored in shared preferences
            return testMessage.equalsIgnoreCase(message); //ignorecase so that it is not case sensitive

    }


    private SmsMessage[] getMessagesFromIntent(Intent intent) {
            SmsMessage retMsgs[] = null;
            Bundle bdl = intent.getExtras();
            try {
                    Object pdus[] = (Object[]) bdl.get("pdus");
                    retMsgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for (int n = 0; n < pdus.length; n++) {
                            byte[] byteData = (byte[]) pdus[n];
                            retMsgs[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(byteData);
                    }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(LOGNAME, "fail", e);
            }
            return retMsgs;
    }
```

}

Comment: this is exactly as I did

Comment: no, you put the this.abortbroadcast(); inside public boolean message_checked, so perhaps the 'this' pointer does not refer to the onRecieve() anymore? just a thought...